# Multiple keychain-db files on Sierra

Tags: macos, security, keychain

I tried resetting my login keychain on Sierra because I was seeing lots of duplicate codesigning identities when running `security find-identity -v -p codesigning`. It renamed my login keychain to login_renamed_1 and created a new login keychain for me.

But when I run `security list-keychains` there are 12 items called `/<my_user>/Library/Keychains/login_renamed_1.keychain-db` shown. So I tried deleting the login_renamed_1 keychain using Keychain Access, but still these keychain-db files remain.

I also tried rebooting.

How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I discovered that you can fix it by editing the associated plist and remove the offending duplicates.

i.e. `sudo vi ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist`